# jQuery UI toggleClass duration behaving strangely

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, toggleclass

I'm using jQuery UI  .toggleClass(class, [duration]) to toggle a red background on a 100x100 box, but the results I'm getting are strange. See http://jqueryui.com/docs/toggleClass/ for reference.

As you can see from this example - http://jsfiddle.net/xkrX9/ - the **first** click on div#box toggles the red background immediately (without any [duration]) and then toggles it again back to white after approx 1s without a second click event. The **second** click (without reloading the page) results in the .red class being toggled as expected with the 1000ms duration.

What's going wrong here? Thanks for any insight!

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<style>
    #box { width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #999; }
    .red { background: red; }
</style>

<div id="box"></div>

<script>
    $('#box').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('red', 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that it is a bug. If there is no class attribute it will not work, but once you add the class attibute to the node it works fine,

http://jsfiddle.net/xkrX9/3/

I would file a bug report.

**jQUery UI [Bug #8113](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8113)**

Comment: Perfect, this answers the question. Thanks for clarifying Andrew!

Comment: Thanks. I see the css `border` also acts in the similar fashion. Is it too a jQuery bug?

Comment: @maan81 At a glance it looks like a jQuery UI bug, specifically, the animateClass function. It does a lot of `this.attr('class')` and `this.attr('style')` calls, which is the most likely culprit.